# Banning in Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, banning

With Documentation up, many people are bound to jump in and create tags/topics/examples. Since what makes a good example/syntax etc differs from what makes a good answer in the QA section, it would be easy for even seasoned QA answerers to make mistakes.

What also makes things hard is that people are still unsure of the small details of what makes a good post compared to a bad one.

Currently are there any bans in Documentation?

Will there be a period of time (few weeks) where the banning process is more lenient until the Stack Overflow community has a definitive idea of what is accepted and what is not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it's part of Stack Overflow, it gets a lot of that stuff for free. Specifically, you can be warned and even suspended if you abuse your privileges, engage in disruptive or destructive behavior, etc.

[The same rules for behavior apply](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), and the same results should be expected if you violate them.

There are also rate-limits and such that apply to edits; they're pretty generous at the moment, but if you waste them, you gotta wait it out.